# What is the meaning of "gap" in G1 phase?

Tags: cell-biology, terminology, cell-cycle

The full form of G1 phase is Gap one phase. G1 os also called first gap phase. Is there any specific meaning of " gap" here ?

Answer (score 3):

The $G_1$ gap is the period between the last cell division and that start of DNA replication (synthesis). That's what "gap" means here. A period of time between two events. It's [often described](http://cyberbridge.mcb.harvard.edu/mitosis_4.html) as time spent synthesizing proteins, but I prefer to think about it as the period before the signal to start synthesis lands. A cell can do any number of things in the meantime: synthesize proteins, grow, interact with other cells, move, differentiate, enter and exit $G_0$...

[image]

Albert's has a [good chapter on the overview of the cell cycle](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26869/) and on the [control system](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26824/)